# SwiftUI Menu Button Displayed as Disabled Initially

Tags: macos, swiftui

On macOS, SwiftUI Menu buttons appear initially disabled. Once you click on them, they activate as normal and display properly. This code replicates the problem:

```swift
Menu {
    Button("First") { }
    Button("Second") { }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
}
.padding()
```

Which initially will look like this:

[image]

Then after clicking on the button:

[image]

- Preview shows correctly, but a running app behaves as above
- The contents of the menu don't seem to affect the result
- Tried explicitly mucking with disabled state using `.disabled(false)`; no joy since it isn't really disabled

I could just set the foreground color of the image, but I was hoping to figure out the real problem. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Setting the foreground doesn't work either. Still visibly disabled.

Comment: Have the same issue. Would also be interested to see an answer for that.

Comment: Testing the code on 12.0, it looks like the problem is fixed!

Comment: Yup, I'm testing on macOS 12.1 and the bug appears fixed. Thanks for the heads up @Taylor

Comment: I’m still seeing this issue on macOS Monterey 12.6.1 (21G217).

Answer (score 2):

This bug (filed as FB8976414) remains as of macOS 11.3. I got some help from @kontiki on a workaround, though. If you include a `Button` along with the `Menu`, it displays properly enabled. Don't ask me why. You can make the `Button` zero-sized so it doesn't affect your layout and just remove it when (if?) the bug gets fixed.

**-- Update --**

As of macOS 11.4, this technique no longer works. The `Menu` always displays as disabled until it's clicked. I guess if you look on the bright side, at least it's more consistent!

**--  --**

```swift
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Menu {
        Button("First") { }
        Button("Second") { }
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
    }

    Button("", action: {}).scaleEffect(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

**-- Update 2 --**

As of macOS 12.0 according to @Taylor (verified by me in macOS 12.1), the bug is fixed. Thanks, Apple engineers!

Comment: In my case on 10.4, the menu is enabled appearance when it loads, however then turns to disabled appearance after an option is selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be fixed on macOS 12.3.1.

Comment: I should clarify, the issue I am seeing persists in window toolbars. Same issue I found [on Twitter.](https://twitter.com/oskargroth/status/1471820701606764551)