# Button grayed out in toolbar initially

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI macOS application, and I noticed that when you have a button in a `toolbar`, its image is initially grayed out until you hover over or click it.

I am using macOS Montery Beta 3, and Xcode 13 Beta 3.

### Simple Reproduction

1. Create a new SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Panel1").padding()
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            Text("Panel2").padding()
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the application, and you should see that the plus button is grayed out. However hovering over or clicking it makes the button not gray.

This question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602163/swiftui-menu-button-displayed-as-disabled-initially), but instead with a `toolbar`.

Whats happening here?

Comment: That is very strange. I spun up the code on my end, but it is not behaving the way you described. It is blue when my app starts. You could potentially force the color and prevent it from being gray in the first place. You would add a .foregroundColor modifier to your Image like so: Image(systemName: "plus").foregroundColor(.black)

Comment: @nickreps Are you using the beta version of macOS? I didn't state the version because the linked question was on a older version of macOS, and it still seemed to have this issue

Comment: Nope, I am using 11.4 - not the beta. I wonder why it works on my end but not on your end. What will this button do? Is it going to be a navigation link? If so, try putting a navigation link with the plus image and see if that works. If this is the case and you need help with the code, let me know. EDIT: Maybe I should add, I am using Xcode beta 13, not sure if that could be why it works. Is this a simulator only bug, or have you emulated directly on your device and it occurs there as well?

Comment: @nickreps The button is just used for adding items. I think this might be a bug with the beta version of macOS

Comment: @nickreps Wait, I thought you can't simulate a macOS app on macOS? Wouldn't you just run it directly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68422383/6576315

Comment: @RTXGamer ToolbarItemGroup doesn't seem to help, but thanks for the effort

Comment: As pointed out above, this is a duplicate question. I posted an answer to it at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994169/899918

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and discovered that you need to specify the color explicitly.

```swift
.toolbar {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }
    Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Caveat: This means that a `.disabled(true)`  ViewModifier on `Button` doesn't change the button to a disabled appearance. This will need to be handled manually.